# Changing value of a boolean variable within a method without using it as a parameter (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I have a multiple choice question with four answer choices and if the user selects the fourth option, I want to add an item to a scrollable list in another class.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    boolean ArtClub = false;

    public void onRadioButtonClicked1(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.q1o1://performing arts
                if (checked) {
                    //algorithm implementation
                    break;
                }

            case R.id.q1o2://literature/film
                if (checked) {
                    //algorithm implementation
                    break;
                }

            case R.id.q1o3://music/dance
                if (checked) {
                    //algorithm implementation
                    break;
                }

            case R.id.q1o4://visual arts
                if (checked) {
                    //algorithm implementation
                    ArtClub = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I attempt to call ArtClub from another class, it always returns false. How do I make it so that selecting the fourth option makes ArtClub true within the method and can still be accessed as such from another class?

Edit: I've figured it out, just had to make a separate class with public static boolean variables

Comment: Can you provide the declaration of the class and the declaration of ArtClub ?

Comment: It should return true when polling for its value.

Comment: I added the class declaration and declaration of ArtClub

Comment: @willschrepf how are you accessing `ArtClub` from your other class?

Answer (score 0):

Create an utility class and declare in that class, for example, `public static boolean ArtClub = false;`. You'll be able to access the attribute from any other class/service etc